# How to test an AMD athlon 64 X2 processor? Accidentally connected AM2+ processor in AM2 socket

Tags: cpu, amd-athlon

I have a motherboard with an AM2 socket. Recently I bought a new processor from Amazon which is AM2+. The new processor seemed to fit into the socket so I plugged it in but I wouldn't boot. Then I did some research and found out that I got the wrong processor. How do I know if the processor was damaged?

Answer (score 3):

The [wiki article on AM2+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2%2B) suggests that the socket is designed for interoperation with AM2 processors.  While your AM2+ CPU would likely not function in an AM2 mobo, it seems highly unlikely that you could have damaged the CPU.

> Socket AM2+ is a CPU socket, which is the immediate successor to Socket AM2 that is used by several AMD processors such as Athlon 64 X2. Socket AM2+ is a mid-migration from Socket AM2 to Socket AM3 and **both AM2+ and AM2 socket CPUs and motherboards have the potential to operate together**. Actual interoperability depends upon other factors, especially the availability of compatible BIOS software, and some PC retailers, such as Dell, have not provided compatible BIOS versions that allow use of socket AM2+ CPUs on their products utilizing socket AM2 motherboards, such as the Inspiron 531.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Yup, you just need a BIOS update if an AM2+ doesn't work in an AM2 socket.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't dealt with this stuff in a loooooong time, but for well over a decade, if a CPU fit into a socket without a hammer, it would not be damaged at power-on (even if it wasn't compatible). Socket 939 and Socket 940 were essentially the same, but one was for server-grade CPUs and one was for consumer-grade CPUs. They were almost pin-compatible, but not quite -- hence the very slightly different socket.

There might have been a couple of exceptions to this, but by-and-large it was the case.

So, *if* that holds true today (big if, granted), your CPU should be fine.

Sorry I can't be of more assistance with this.

Comment: I agree, with the added caveat that the chip was properly aligned in terms of rotation.

Comment: @Software: It would not have gone into the socket if pin 1 on the package was not correctly aligned with pin 1 on the socket -- and if it would have, the socket is poorly designed. This is what I meant by "without a hammer". Back in my day, they only went in (and they dropped right in) if pin 1 was properly aligned. And get off my lawn.

Comment: Ahh yes, of course, you're right.